# Expect Script send reboot never processed by machine

Tags: bash, ssh, tcl, expect

I've written an expect script that will ssh into a raspberry pi, then a custom built radio device. It will md5 a file on the filesystem, and then compare it with a known good md5. Then it will issue a command to reboot the device. The problem is that the "send "reboot\r"" command is never actually processed by the radio device. Expect sends it to the right expect_id, but just nothing happens.

I've tried moving the line around in the script. The funny thing is it will work when it is placed ABOVE the md5sum call. If it's made any time after the md5sum call, it will never work. I've tried using the fully qualified path of the reboot command, and without. Neither work. See the below code. The custom radio device is running an old version of the linux kernel. I've written 2 to 3 other scripts that work on these radios and reboot them regularly throughout the scripts. However, for this particular script, it simply doesn't work (depending on the location of the line of code).

```
send "md5sum /root/BS5000/bs_config.xml\r\n"
sleep 3

send "/sbin/reboot\r"
```

There are no error messages here, it just does nothing. It SHOULD issue the reboot command.

Comment: I notice that you have a \n at the end of the first command but not at the end of the second one. What do you want to achieve with the \n? Aside from this, Do you get the same effect with `send "md5sum /root/BS5000/bs_config.xml; send "/sbin/reboot\r"?

Comment: Have you tried doing an `expect` after each of the `send`s to check if they've been processed by the other side?

Comment: @user1250991: Sorry, mistake in my comment. I meant of course `send "md5sum /root/BS5000/bs_config.xml;/sbin/reboot\r"`.

Comment: @DonalFellows : I think, while a clean solution would use `expect` to be on the safe side, if the `md5sum` runs fast enough, the `sleep` should do as well. I rather suspect the `\n` to be the culprit, because after the first command has been sent (terminated by \r), the next character in the input buffer would be a \n. Don't know what effect this might have, but it certainly does not belong there.

Comment: @user1250991 : BTW, what is the purpose to write the MD5 of this file to stdout before doing the reboot?

Comment: my first tip in debugging expect scripts: add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the script, or run it with `expect -d`, then examine the debugging output carefully.

Comment: DonalFellows mentioned "after *each* send". You focused on the first one, while the important one is the last send command. Without an `expect` after that, the script finishes which kills the spawned ssh, possibly before it had a chance to relay the reboot command.

Comment: Update. I solved this problem. I agree that the \n could be an issue, but, even with it still there, i solved it. The current fixed code is:

 set timeout 3
 send "md5sum /root/BS5000/bs_config.xml\r\n"
 expect eof
 expect "*"
 sleep 3

  send "/sbin/reboot\r"
  sleep 1
  send "/sbin/reboot\r"
`
Basically to get it to work I had to issue the reboot command twice with a 1 sec sleep in between them. I don't know why this works, and I'm sure there's a better solution out there.

@user1250991: I write the md5 out to std out for debugging purposes.

Comment: @user1934428 I just removed the \n on the md5sum line and it didn't change anything. I still had to double-send the reboot command with a 1 sec sleep between them.

Comment: And if you do the `reboot` manually, you don't have to issue it a second time? In this case, I guess that the issue is the problem explained by SchelteBron above: Since you don't have a `expect` after the reboot, the reboot command will be immidiately killed. Thinking of it, since you reboot anyway, a single `send /sbin/reboot\r`, followed by `interact`, should do the same.

Comment: Well I can't reboot it manually, because then the connection is severed and any following commands cannot be sent and cannot be interpreted by the radio. However there is a possible answer below I will respond to.

Answer (score 0):

You really seem to be missing the "expect" part of [expect](/questions/tagged/expect) -- You should really be trying to write like:

```
spawn something
expect something
send something
expect something
...
```

So:

```
send "md5sum /root/BS5000/bs_config.xml\r"
expect "*"
send "/sbin/reboot\r"
expect eof
```

If you find you need to add sleeps, then your expect patterns are not right. While developing an expect script, run it with `expect -d` or add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the code.

Comment: I already do use exp_internal 1 when developing my scripts until it works flawlessly and then I turn it off.

I also have an expect eof and then expect "*" after the md5sum call. I will however try an "expect eof" line after the reboot call, although historically in all other scripts that reboot these devices, no reboot call has ever required it. I'll try it when I get into work today. Thanks

Comment: So, what does the debugging output show after the first "send reboot"?

Comment: So, changing this to expect eof after the first reboot call, does seem to fix the issue, and it no longer requires a sleep and then a second call. I am curious however as to why my other scripts which call the same reboot executable on the same pieces of hardware (with the exact same linux kernel version), don't require the expect eof after the reboot call.

Comment: For what the debug stuff says for the first reboot call, its the same for the first and the second it simply says:

send: sending "/sbin/reboot\r" to {exp6}
send: sending "/sbin/reboot\r" to {exp6}

I can't explain why the eof line fixes it in this particular case, but it does seem to work. I did get the feeling that having to send a command multiple times did seem dirty and it seemed like there was probably a better approach out there.